# How I can get the request XML using WebAPI C#

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

When I can sent the restfull request to web API , How to receive the Body/payload and headers of the request in controller post method.

```
public HttpResponseMessage post(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {

        var RequestBody = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;
        var Headers = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers;
```

Here I able to get the headers values but unable to get the body request. Could any one suggest me how I can get the body?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to create an action method in your controller that looks like this,

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessge> Post(HttpRequestMessage request) {
   Var bodyStream = await request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
}
```

Comment: I have tried that one, I am able to get the headers values but not getting the body. I writen the code for body is: var RequestBody = HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream;

Comment: @user3440240 If you can't use the async/await then use .ContinueWith instead.  Don't use .Result under a ASP.Net runtime based host.

Answer (score 0):

```
 client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(ur);

            if(JsonType is JsonMediaTypeFormatter)
            // Add an Accept header for JSON / XMLformat.
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            else
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/xml"));

            return client;

 HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<Requestclass>(requestClassObject, WebApiClient.JsonType);

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("path",content).Result;
```